# Rails 3.1: Form_for content is displayed outside of <form></form> tags on index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The form_for partial displays and works perfectly in the Product's show page, but when I add the partial to each item in the product index page the form content is displayed but it is outside of the  tags (The form consists of radio buttons for a rating system styled form(No ajax - works with submit button). The correct radio buttons are selected where they exist and submission still seems to work correctly).
The weirdest part about this is (in both chrome and firefox) when I view source the content is inside the  tags, but when I use 'inspect element' the content is outside of the  tags. This is a problem because my css and jquery can't find the content in the form element (The element is found in the show page).

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Details are below:
**Ruby:** 1.9.3p0
**Rails:** 3.1.3
I have three models: User, Product and TasteNote(Appearance, aroma, taste, texture, drinkability and a text area for comments).

**Routes:**

```
Appname::Application.routes.draw do
 resources :users
 resources :products
 resources :taste_notes
```

**Models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :taste_notes, :foreign_key  => :user_id, :dependent => :destroy


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :taste_notes, :foreign_key  => :product_id, :dependent => :destroy


class TasteNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id, :appearance, :aroma, :taste,
                  :texture, :drinkability, :comments

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product

  validates :user_id,    :presence => true
  validates :product_id, :presence => true
```

**Products Controller:**

```
def show
  ..
  ...
  if @taste_note = current_user.taste_notes.where(:product_id => @product.id).first
  else
    @taste_note = TasteNote.new(:product_id => @product.id)
  end
end
```

**Product Show page call to partial:**

```
..
...
<%= render :partial => "tnote", :locals => {:product => @product, :taste_note => @taste_note} %>
...
..
```

**Product index page:**

```
..
...
<% get_tasting_note(product) %> <!-- This returns @taste_note -->
<%= render :partial => "tnote", :locals => {:product => product, :taste_note => @taste_note} %>
...
..
```

**product_helper.rb**

```
def get_tasting_note(product)
  if @taste_note = current_user.taste_notes.where(:product_id => product.id).first
    @taste_note
  else
    @taste_note = current_user.taste_notes.build(:product_id => product.id)
  end
end
```

**Taste Note Partial (_tnote.html.erb):**

```
<div id="taste_note">
  <hr>
  <h3>Tasting Notes:</h3>

  <%= form_for taste_note, :html => { :class => "rating_ballot_index", :id => "edit_taste_note_#{taste_note.id}" } do |f| %>

    <% [ 'appearance', 'aroma', 'taste', 'texture', 'drinkability' ].each do |attribute| %>
      <br><br><%= attribute.humanize %><br>
      <% (1..5).each do |level| %>
        <%= f.label("#{attribute}_#{level}_#{product.id}", content_tag(:span, level), :class=>"taste_note #{attribute}") %>
        <%= radio_button_tag("taste_note[#{attribute}]", level, current_user_taste_note("#{attribute}", product.id) == level, :class => "taste_note_button #{attribute}", :id => "taste_note_#{attribute}_#{level}_#{product.id}") %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <br><br>
    <%= f.label :comments %><br><br>
    <%= f.text_area :comments, :rows => 5 %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "submit" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**product_helper.rb - current_user_taste_note()**

```
  # Show page gets product id from params[:id]
  # Index page can not, so pass in productid parameter
  def current_user_taste_note(value, productid = params[:id])

    if value == "appearance"
      if @taste_note = current_user.taste_notes.find_by_product_id(productid)
        @taste_note.appearance
      else
        "N/A"
      end
    elsif value == "aroma"
      if @taste_note = current_user.taste_notes.find_by_product_id(productid)
        @taste_note.aroma
      else
        "N/A"
      end
    elsif value == "taste"
      if @taste_note = current_user.taste_notes.find_by_product_id(productid)
        @taste_note.taste
      else
        "N/A"
      end
    elsif value == "texture"
      if @taste_note = current_user.taste_notes.find_by_product_id(productid)
        @taste_note.texture
      else
        "N/A"
      end
    elsif value == "drinkability"
      if @taste_note = current_user.taste_notes.find_by_product_id(productid)
        @taste_note.drinkability
      else
        "N/A"
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: maybe you are trying to nest forms in forms? this is not allowed and your browser will try to correct it.

Comment: No, this doesn't seem to be the issue (unless I am doing something wrong). I tried allowing nested attributes but to no avail. Furthermore, I have a similar form for 'favourite' items that displays perfectly in the same location as the taste notes.
Any other recommendations as to what might be causing the problem? Been trying to figure it out for two days now. I'm stumped.

Comment: Ok, after two days of torture, I  figured out I had an open </table> tag, that was causing all the problems.

Comment: You may want to answer your question and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake.
I had an open  tag that was causing all the problems.

Comment: You should consider switching to haml.